# Command similar to `tail -f file.txt` for listing directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Is there a command similar to what we have for files which gives content of the file as it grows:

```
tail -f file.txt
```

I am searching for something like this for listing directory content which shows me the list of files in the directory as and when they get created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `watch`:

**Linux**:

```
watch ls # default is 2 second interval
```

(adjust the interval with `-n`):

```
watch -n1 ls # 1 second interval
```

**Alternative**: (eg. **macOS** doesn't have `watch` natively):

```
while :; do clear; ls; sleep 2; done
```

**macOS**: (via **MacPorts** or **homebrew**)

```
port install watch # install watch via MacPorts
brew install watch # install watch via homebrew
```

Comment: `watch` is available on macOS via **homebrew**, with `brew install watch`.

Comment: The problem with `watch` as a solution for the OP is that its a screen based. True it will show a growing list of files, but once that list grows off the screen, it will show no more files. That limit will be different according to what your terminal window is sized at...

Answer (score 5):

You said you're on Linux. The Linux kernel has something called `inotify`, and `inotify-tools` gives us the command line tools `inotify-wait` and `inotify-watch`, which can print out any low-level events happening in the files/directories you're watching.

Example:

```
$ inotifywait -e CREATE -m . &
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
$ touch foo
./ CREATE foo # inotifywait output
$ touch foof
./ CREATE foof
```

Where `-e CREATE` specifies to watch out for file creation, and `-m` specifies that the program should not exit after the first event received.

Comment: Very good solution. A complete solution might show the current list and then just the names of new files as they are added: `ls && (inotifywait -e CREATE -m . |  cut -d' ' -f3-)`

Comment: @Guss There's an unavoidable race condition there, involving files that might be created after the first job runs but before the second. You can start `inotifywait` first, in which case you might see the in-between files twice, but as far as I know there's no way to see each file exactly once.